# MongoDb: Creating User in $external via Java Driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

We would need to create Users in $external to allow them to login via LDAP.
On command shell, the following command:

```
db.getSiblingDB('$external').createUser({ user : 'username', roles: [ { role: 'dbOwner', db: 'databasename' } ] } )
```

is working fine.

But as far as we are executing the same command via Java Driver, we are getting exceptions.

Java Code:

```
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("$external");
String command = "db.getSiblingDB('$external').createUser({ user : '"+ userName +"', roles: [ { role: 'dbOwner', db: 'CMRepWs_'"+userName.toUpperCase()+"' } ] } )";

CommandResult result = db.command(command);
```

Result Message:

```
{ "serverUsed" : "lblasa1t.cm-cic.fr:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "no such command: db.getSiblingDB('$external').createUser({ user : 'username', roles: [ { role: 'dbOwner', db: 'CMRepWs_username' } ] } )" , "code" : 59 , "bad cmd" : { "db.getSiblingDB('$external').createUser({ user : 'username', roles: [ { role: 'dbOwner', db: 'CMRepWs_username' } ] } )" : true}}
```

We are running MongoDb Version 3.0.1 with Java Driver 2.13.1.

It would be great, if anybody has an idea of how we can create users in $external via the Java Driver.

Many thanks and best regards,
Jakob

**EDIT:**

We also used the following code to test:

```
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("$external");

    String dbOwner = "dbOwner";
    String dbName = "CMRepWs_" + userName.toUpperCase();
    String role = "{ role: '" + dbOwner + "', db: '" + dbName + "'}";
    Map<String, Object> commandArguments = new BasicDBObject();

    String[] roles = new String[] { role };
    commandArguments.put("createUser", userName);
    commandArguments.put("roles", roles);
    BasicDBObject command = new BasicDBObject(commandArguments);
    CommandResult result = db.command(command);
```

Which results in:

```
{ "serverUsed" : "server:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "No role named { role: 'dbOwner', db: 'CMRepWs_Username'}@$external" , "code" : 31}
```

Within the CommandResult Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is working fine:

```
    DB db = client.getDB("$external");
    CommandResult result = db.command(new BasicDBObject("createUser",userName).append("roles", Collections.singletonList(new BasicDBObject("role", "dbOwner").append("db", "CMRepWs_Username"))));
    result.throwOnError();
```

So also for the role a new BasicDBObject need to be greated.

Regards,
Jakob